# Previously working script now fails to generate csv file. Why?

Tags: python, json, csv, web-scraping, web-crawler

title can be misleading: python script WORKS, but fails to generate a csv file as it previously had no problem of doing

Source:

```
import requests
import unicodecsv as csv
import json

api_url = 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=8710117352111766&v=2&limit=100000&format=json'
number= 0
SearchTerm = 'McKinsey'
countries = set(['us','ar','au','at','bh','be','br','ca','cl','cn','co','cz','dk','fi','fr','de','gr','hk','hu','in','id','ie','il','it','jp','kr','kw','lu','my','mx','nl','nz','no','om','pk','pe','ph','pl','pt','qa','ro','ru','sa','sg','za','es','se','ch','tw','tr','ae','gb','ve'])


with open( SearchTerm + '.csv' , 'a' ) as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['city','company','country','date','expired','formattedLocation','formattedLocationFull','formattedRelativeTime','indeedApply','jobkey','jobtitle','latitude','longitude','onmousedown','snippet','source','sponsored','state','url']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames, lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writeheader()

    for SCountry in countries:

        Country = SCountry #this is the variable assigned to the country

        urlfirst = api_url + '&co=' + Country + '&q=' + SearchTerm

        grabforNum = requests.get(urlfirst)
        json_content = json.loads(grabforNum.content)
        print(json_content["totalResults"])

        numresults = (json_content["totalResults"])
        # must match the actual number of job results to the lower of the 25 increment or the last page will repeat over and over 

        for number in range(0, numresults, 25): 
            url = api_url + '&co=' + Country + '&q=' + SearchTerm + '&latlong=1' + '&start=' + str(number)
            response = requests.get(url)
            grabforclean = json.loads(response.content)
            clean_json = (grabforclean['results'])
            print 'Complete '+ url

            for job in clean_json:
                writer.writerow(job)
```

This is the original owner of the script. I was using it 3 days ago until I had to reinstall my operating system. Now for some reason, it fails to store all the content it collects into a CSV file. API key works, no error messages. `requests` `unicodecsv` and `json` are all installed.

stuff like this really drives me up the wall, how can you diagnose something that previously worked? I had multiple versions of the script searching for different keywords so I know my modifications are not to blame, but perhaps something outside the script is broken.

Comment: maybe the site changed? have you tried including prints all over your code to check where it isn't reaching?

Comment: When I execute the program it spits out links via the api which I could then visit. So I know the data is there.  If the field names in the API changed then an error would pop up.

Comment: Debug it the same way as you would if it were just written. I'd suggest finding or creating the smallest dataset that will reproduce the problem and then using a debugger or perhaps `assert` statements to verify that what is going on is correct.

Comment: @Paul Rooney yes. Same python version.

Comment: @martinau I will try using 'assert' statements

Comment: `ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: u'stations'`

Comment: Try adding `extrasaction='ignore'` to your `csv.DictWriter` parameters. You need to decide how to handle new fields.

Answer (score 0):

The website has probably recently started returning a new field, so you have two choices:

1. Add `stations` to your list of `fieldnames`.
2. Add `extrasaction='ignore'` to your `csv.Dictwriter` parameters to keep all your existing fields and ignore any new ones that are added.

Both of these solutions will allow your script to work again.